# Leaflet: Hide/Show Markers that are being inserted dynamically into the map

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, leaflet, show-hide

i'm inserting the map points like this:

```
function getPoints() {
  $.getJSON("get_users.php", function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var location = new L.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].lng);
      var name = data[i].name;
      var website = data[i].website;
      var teste = "teste" + website;

      var marker = new L.Marker(location, {
        icon: tree1
      });
      marker.bindPopup("<a onclick='info()' style='font-size:18px; font-style: italic; font-family:courier; cursor: pointer;'>" + name + "</a><p>" + city + "</p><p id='inf' style='display:none;'>" + website + "</p><p style='font-size:10px;'>" + location + "</p>", {maxWidth: '400'});
      users.addLayer(marker);
    }
  }).complete(function() {
    if (firstLoad == true) {
      map.fitBounds(users.getBounds());
      firstLoad = false;
    };
  });
}
```

And i wanted the users to be able to only see the markers, for example with the class "foo", using  javascript to hide the points that don't have that class.

My problem is that i have not been able to assign a class to the marker.. i have tried:

Using JQuery: `$(marker._icon).addClass(foo)` , `$(marker).addClass('foo')`

DomUtil: `DomUtil.addClass(marker, 'foo')` , `marker = L.DomUtil.addClass(marker, 'foo')`

Am i doing something wrong declaring the class? please correct me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an array of LayerGroups with your markers and then, with a sub array, you can put only the markers you want to show, and remove and add whenever you want it

Answer (score 1):

Although Leaflet does indeed use DOM elements to render the markers on the map, it provides its own way of manipulating them.

Instead of relying on classes, add your markers into *Layer Groups*, which you can manipulate with Leaflet like other layers. You can `addTo` map and map `removeLayer` the desired Group to show / hide its containing markers.